# How to refresh tinymce iframe?

Tags: tinymce

How can I refresh the tinymce content or refresh the tinymce iframe using jquery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code is used to refresh tinymce:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRepaint");
```

Comment: What is the equivalent of this line if you are using the TinyMCE jQuery plugin?

Comment: Adding this for reference to find the latest commands. 
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-command-identifiers/

Answer (score 6):

You can use this statement to refresh (replace) the content:

```
editor.execCommand('mceSetContent', false, html);
```

Or if you want to make sure the dirty flag is cleared:

```
editor.execCommand('mceSetContent', false, html);
editor.startContent = tinymce.trim(editor.getContent({ format: 'raw' }));
editor.isNotDirty = true;
editor.nodeChanged();
```